# Using Green's theorem.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I'm asked to find the following integral by using Green's theorem:
$$
I=\iint_D \frac{2ay-y^2-x^2}{y}dxdy
$$
where $D$ is the region enclosed by the curve $x^2+y^2=2ay$ and $y\geq a$.

The only thing they taught me, in theory, was the statement of the theorem so I have no idea where to start solving this exercise. If someone can show me how to start or show a meaningful example I would appreciate it.

Comment: I am sure your textbook has some solved examples? Also you can see examples of problems solved online - go to Paul's online notes etc. or even search this site for examples. Once you have made an effort to solve yourself and if you get stuck, please edit the post to show us how far you got and where you got stuck.

Comment: Who are referring to when you say, "they"?

Comment: my calculus teacher @Shaun

Comment: For starters, completing the square in the equation for (part of) the boundary of $D$ gives$$x^2+y^2=2ay \implies x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$$Does this equation look familiar to you?